# How do I create "accessible" PDFs from HTML?

Tags: html, pdf-generation, usability, accessibility

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to generate accessible PDFs (including images) from HTML?

The PDFs need to look like the original HTML, including positions of images etc.
Any special HTML structure required to help make the final PDF accessible?

- I've seen questions about creating PDFS none of them specifically address the important issue of accessibility.

My poison of choice is Perl but references to any program, language or library will help.

I have a more in-depth question at TypeDoc if anyone has more general information to offer.
http://doctype.com/TiB

Also,
I, and others, would find it useful if users with accessibility problems could comment if they find the "usability experience" of using PDFs  better or worse than reading from Plain Old Semantic HTML (POSH).

Thanks
Mike

Comment: The problem is that HTML doesn't look like anything. Although many browsers make it look the same, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com/). Through CSS you can control margins, page breaking and orientation. While not open source, you can try it for free, but it places a small water mark in the upper right corner.

Comment: Are there any PrinceXML samples that are actually accessible/tagged PDF? I checked a few samples on the website, and they were not tagged PDF. There is no option for accessible/tagged PDF in the documentation.

Comment: PrinceXML does not currently support accessible/tagged PDFs. PDFReactor does though.

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe ColdFusion server product does a really fine job of this, not surprisingly.   But it's not free, and the open source implementations of the language (Smith and BlueDragon) don't support the pdf stuff.

Developer licenses to Adobe ColdFusion are free, and you can download it.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this thing on a small scale but scripting Safari to print to PDFs. I don't recommend it for large-scale projects though.

Comment: Likewise. I hacked together a system using http://automatorworld.com/archives/download-urls-as-pdfs/. It worked, but the pdf's consistently look bad; flow across page breaks isn't implemented.

Answer (score 0):

By far the most capable PDF publishing tool I've ever come across is [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/). There is an open source library written with Python and a proprietary system that allows you to construct a document using RML, a custom xml spec. The latter is easier for more complex docs. They tend to be very flexible (and reasonable) with pricing.

Not strictly an answer to your question as it doesn't handle html-to-pdf conversions, but perhaps of use to you.

Comment: The OP asked for a tool that produces *accessible* PDF output, and I don't see this mentioned in the ReportLab documentation.